# Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type have the same primary key value

Tags: c#

I use repository pattern in asp.net mvc 5, I select the data from table  and then add one entity in this data with value and I want to set this data in database with added entity value but Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'BlogPost.DAL.Entity.BlogPost.Blog' have the same primary key value error is occured but in database this row is inserted what I need to do avoid this error.

```
model = await _IBlogSerices.BlogGetByID(Id);
Blog data = _db.Blog.Find(Id);
_db.Blog.Remove(data);
_db.SaveChanges();
model.IsPublish = true;
await _IBlogSerices.CreateBlog(model);
return View();
```

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image

Comment: What you are doing is, removing a Blog and creating a blog with the same Id. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

it seem there is not problem if you BlogGetByID(Id) function like

```
public Task<Blog> BlogGetByID(int id){
  return _db.Blog.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id ==id);
}
```